# Update view bugs when data in firebase changes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

[This is when I launch the app and it looks ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khutD.png)[This is when I change some data from firebase, as you can see some data is not arranged in the right way and some rectangles are double](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPqPJ.png)I'm currently working on this project where I need do read data from Firebase and update my views from the changes. Every time my data changes on firebase my views bugs in strange ways.

This is my Student class

```
struct Student : Identifiable {
    var id : String
    var name : String
    var surname : String
    var isAbsent : Bool
    var isBathroom : Bool
}
```

Here where I get my data from firebase and publish to get all other views the data

```
class getStudents: ObservableObject {

    @Published var datas = [Student]()

    init() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let classRef = db.collection("5SA")

        classRef.order(by: "surname").addSnapshotListener {(snap,error) in
            if error != nil{
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }


            for i in snap!.documentChanges{

                let id = i.document.documentID
                let name = i.document.get("name")as! String
                let surname = i.document.get("surname") as! String
                let isAbsent = i.document.get("absent") as! Bool
                let isBathroom = i.document.get("bathroom") as! Bool


                self.datas.append(Student(id: id, name: name, surname: surname, isAbsent: isAbsent, isBathroom: isBathroom))

              if i.type == .modified{
                    let isAbsent = i.document.get("absent") as! Bool
                    let isBathroom = i.document.get("bathroom") as! Bool
                    for j in 0..<self.datas.count{

                        if self.datas[j].id == id{

                            self.datas[j].isAbsent = isAbsent
                            self.datas[j].isBathroom = isBathroom
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

    }
}
}
```

This are my views. Apart from the landscape on the iPad simulator the bugs every time.
What I'm trying to achieve is creating like a class app. Where there are students absent, in the toilet or present. I want to to show every student with a rectangle with his name on it and to change color of the rectangles every time the bools on my fire base changes(isAbsent,isBathroom). But when I try to change value on firebase the rectangles multiplies and do strange thinks.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var students = getStudents()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{

            VStack{
                ScrollView{
                Text("Menu")
                Menu().background(Color.white)
                Text("Future verifiche")
                HStack{
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).frame(width:300,height: 300).foregroundColor(.white).overlay(Text("V. Matematica"))
                    }
                }
                Text("Oggi")
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Assenti ")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("In bagno")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Presenti")
                    Spacer()
                }
                HStack{
                    Spacer()

                    ScrollView{
                        ForEach(students.datas,id: \.id){student in
                            VStack(spacing: 15){
                                if student.isAbsent{
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).frame(width:200,height: 100).foregroundColor(self.getColor(isAbsent: student.isAbsent, isBathroom: student.isBathroom)).overlay(Text(student.name))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    ScrollView{
                        ForEach(students.datas,id: \.id){student in
                            VStack(spacing: 15){
                                if student.isBathroom{
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).frame(width:200,height: 100).foregroundColor(self.getColor(isAbsent: student.isAbsent, isBathroom: student.isBathroom)).overlay(Text(student.name))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    ScrollView{
                        ForEach(students.datas,id: \.id){student in
                            VStack(spacing: 15){
                                if !student.isAbsent && !student.isBathroom{
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).frame(width:200,height: 100).foregroundColor(self.getColor(isAbsent: student.isAbsent, isBathroom: student.isBathroom)).overlay(Text(student.name))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Classe 5SA",displayMode: .inline)
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())

    }
    func getColor(isAbsent: Bool, isBathroom : Bool) -> Color {
        if isAbsent{
            return Color.red
        }
        if isBathroom{
            return Color.blue
        }
        return Color.green
    }
}


struct Menu : View {

    var body : some View{
        HStack{
            NavigationLink(destination: Studenti()){

                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).frame(width: 150,height: 150).foregroundColor(.red).opacity(0.5).overlay(Text("Studenti").foregroundColor(.black))

            }
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Overview")){

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).frame(width: 150,height: 150).foregroundColor(.green).opacity(0.5).overlay(Text("Overview").foregroundColor(.black))

            }
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Orario")){
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).frame(width: 150,height: 150).foregroundColor(.blue).opacity(0.5).overlay(Text("Orario").foregroundColor(.black))
            }

            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Calendario")){

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).frame(width: 150,height: 150).foregroundColor(.orange).opacity(0.5).overlay(Text("Calendario").foregroundColor(.black))

            }
        }
    }
}

struct Studenti : View {
    @ObservedObject var students = getStudents()
    var body : some View {
        ForEach(students.datas,id: \.id){student in
            VStack{
                Rectangle().frame(width:300,height: 150).foregroundColor(self.getColor(isAbsent: student.isAbsent, isBathroom: student.isBathroom)).overlay(Text(student.name))
            }
        }
    }
    func getColor(isAbsent: Bool, isBathroom : Bool) -> Color {
        if isAbsent{
            return Color.red
        }
        if isBathroom{
            return Color.blue
        }
        return Color.green
    }
}
```

Comment: note that when you have too many Views strange things can happen. Try to group some components into separate Views.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you post  some screenshots of the "bugs" in your layout?

Comment: i have added 2 pic about the app when is first launched and when it bugs

Comment: Please do not put links in questions. Links can break over time and if that happens, it would invalidate the question. Please add the images to your question. It also appears that every time there's a change, a new student object is appended to the dataSource array? `self.datas.append(Student(`

Comment: I’m sorry but it put automatically the links. Yeah could that create problems?

Comment: SO cannot automatically put links. You need to add the images to the question as an image, not a link. Not sure about the followup question but I don't know if it's on purpose but adding a new student every time something changes with *a different student* would be a problem.